# Voltage controlled current line driver for PLC

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, power-line-communication

We are designing a power line communication system using FSK. We are working in narrowband with a carrier frequency at 87.5kHz.

For this system a line driver that increases the available power from the modulator is needed. It should then drive the current of the transformer, which couples it to the power line.

The main requirement is that it should be able to convert a voltage at the input to a current at the output. Summarized it has the following further requirements:

1. The input voltage is a sine wave that oscillates around 2.5V coming
   from the oscillator circuits. About 3V pp.
2. The output needs to be a current with a sine wave with an amplitude of 160 mA (rating of the
   transformer).
3. The output needs to be differential or the topology should be such that it can be connected to the transformer (no DC currents present)
4. It should be linear.

We found that for the 3rd requirement a differential op amp could be used but these were very hard to find for the given current rating, and we wouldn't know how to design a voltage to current converter structure with it.

Another option we thought of was to use a single voltage controlled current amplifier configuration and connect the other side of the transformer to a virtual ground. But we would have some difficulty implementing this and weren't quite sure whether this would result in a good circuit.

Do any of you have any suggestions on topologies or where to look for information regarding this amplifier design.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use a capacitor in series with the transformer's primary to block any DC offset voltage at the output of your voltage-to-current converter?

Comment: any low impedance driver can driver sine current into a known impedance transformer.. but your question has no spectral impedance

Comment: can you build a circuit with higher voltage,  less current output (e.g. 15V 30mA which many op amps will do directly) and use a 1:5 transformer to convert to approx 3V 150ma?

Comment: A capacitor would be possible but is not the most favorable solution. If this would be used, what would be a solution for a topology of a voltage controlled current source where its output goes through a DC blocking capacitor. So how would we go about designing this feedback circuit.

Comment: The impedance of transformer is not known and probably variable, for this reason a current output related to its input voltage is desired.

Comment: I= V(f)/Z(f)  with a bandpass filter  You can't design I without knowing these two variables

Comment: Yeah ofcourse, thats why I want to implement a configuration using a feedback network that compares with voltage over for example a shunt resistor. So using what they do here but then for AC currents with a linear transfer. https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/controlled-current-source